# activeadmin: link_to in a helper does not appear in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got a helper that I'm using for rendering new fields dynamically in my ActiveAdmin form.

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def link_to_add_property_fields(name, f, association)
        new_object = Item::Property.new({item_attribute_id: '', value: ''})
        id = new_object.object_id

        fields = f.semantic_fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
            render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
        end

        fields = fields.to_s.html_safe

        link_to(name, '#', class: 'add_property_fields', data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
    end
end
```

Everything works except the `link_to` doesn't render on the page.
I have tried to render it using `render html:`, but to no avail.
Is there any alternative?

Comment: I've moved on with `f.template.render html: link_to(...)`. This works, but for some reason it prints out the object id on the page like `#<#<Class:0x00000005918098>:0x0000000593e7c0>`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it by throwing out the template.

```
f.render html: link_to(...)
```